# Google container connect to service

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm following a course on PluralSight where the course author puts a docker image onto kubernetes and then access it via his browser. I'm trying to replicate what he does but I cannot manage to reach the website. I believe I might be connecting to the wrong IP.

I have a `ReplicationController` that's running 10 `pods`:

**rc.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
          name: hello-rc
spec:
        replicas: 10
        selector:
                app: hello-world
        template:
             metadata:
                labels:
                        app: hello-world
             spec:
                     containers:
                             - name: hello-pod
                               image: nigelpoulton/pluralsight-docker-ci:latest
                               ports:
                                       - containerPort: 8080
```

I then  tried to expose the rc:

```
kubectl expose rc hello-rc --name=hello-svc --target-port=8080 --type=NodePort


$ kubectl get services
NAME         CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
hello-svc    10.27.254.160   <nodes>       8080:30488/TCP   30s
kubernetes   10.27.240.1     <none>        443/TCP          1h
```

My google container endpoint is : `35.xxx.xx.xxx` and when running `kubectl describe svc hello-svc` the NodePort is `30488`

Thus I try to access the app at `35.xxx.xx.xxx:30488` but the site can’t be reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access your service via the NodePort port, you need to open your firewall for that port (and that instance).

A better way is to create a service of type LoadBalancer (`--type=LoadBalancer`) and access it on the IP Google will give you.

Do not forget to delete the load balancer when you are done.

Comment: Upvote from me, but for purposes of getting through the Pluralsight course, it was easier for me to pop a hole in the firewall. In the realworld I'm sure a `LoadBalancer` is the way to go.